# Custom TextView blocking main thread

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom text view with round corner radius. After testing in instrument, I am finding that it takes 53ms to initialize it (or is it?). I thought 53ms is bit much for one UI component so I was wondering if there is a faster way of doing it? Below are my instrument output and customTextView code.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    private func initialize() {
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 225.0/255, green: 225.0/255, blue: 225.0/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }
}
```

[image: timeProfile]

Comment: how much do you see without setting layer's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do some investigation about that :

Initial time is 83 millisecond.

[image]

Firstly if we do some calculation for layer it will save you 1 millisecond so it is 82 millisecond.

```
 private func initialize() {
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.88, green: 0.88, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1).CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }
```

After disabling of the  `initialize()` method it is 75 millisecond.

[image]

So let just test regular `UITextView` and we see that it is 82 seconds

[image]

**Conclusion it is normal init time for UI element.**